# Generic declaration in method

Tags: java, generics

What does the generic type declaration `<T>` right before the return type of the `get` method in the following code example mean?

```
public interface Listener<T, R> {
    <T> Listener<T, R> get();
}
```

I understand its meaning in the class declaration of `Listener` but I did not find a practical example using `<T>` in that way for a method.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

Comment: thanks you but why it's a bad question and it's being marked with negative points?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'd guess: because you did not show any research effort. If you had said something along the lines of "I studied the tutorial and it says so and so, but how does this fit with this and that?" your question may have been better received. Too many people are too lazy to use a search engine, and people get fed up with that.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to avoid any unnecessary information to be accurate the question, however I'll take your advice, I didn't really know.

Comment: Information that makes your question more specific, higher quality, and not a question that is simply answered by looking at a basic generics tutorial is not "unnecessary information"

Comment: However, it's really good that you ask. Maybe it helps if you read through [ask] and [help]. Then you get a better idea of what this site is and what people expect from your questions, but also what you should expect from answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a method scoped parameterized type. It is defined only in the scope of the `get()` method and it hides the `T` declared in the `Listener` class.
Hiding type is something to avoid and defining a method scoped parameterized type in a generic class is often questionable.

> I want to know what is the role of the parameter in that place.

Here `T` is a type inferred by the client of the method.
But as this `T` is distinct of the `T` declared in the class, it can be a distinct type.
If you want to convert the `T` of the generic class to another type specified by the client it could make sense. 
For example suppose the implementation :

```
public class MyListener implements Listener<String, Integer>{

    @Override
    public <T> Listener<T, Integer> get() {
        return convert to T and return a new instance of Listener...;
    }

}
```

So you could write  :

```
MyListener myListener = new MyListener();
Listener<Float, Integer> listener = myListener.get();
```

Note that the returned `Listener` and `MyListener` are not compatible types.

---

I would add that your interface is actually a functional interface as it declares a single abstract instance method.
Using generic method doesn't allow to use functional interface with lambdas body but only with method references.

For example these could not compile :

```
Listener<String, Integer> invalidListener = () -> new MyListener<String, Integer>();
Listener<String, Integer> invalidListener2 = () -> new MyListener<>();
```

while the method reference will compile :

```
Listener<String, Integer> validListener = MyListener::new;
```

Comment: I just checked this, I had not noticed that behavior before, I'm pretty clear now, thanks you in the other hand I want to know what is bad in my question, it's something i should suppose.

Comment: Your question is not bad at all. I upvoted . Maybe stating that you understand the meaning in the class declaration of `<T>` would make it probably better.

Comment: @JorgeL.Morla: not your down-voter, but your question does not show evidence of prior research into the issue. Yes, you may have done some research, but again there is no concrete evidence of it within the text of the question itself. This site expects much of both questions and answers and encourages members to vote on the perceived quality of both.

Answer (score 2):

This is a method specific parametrized type, but... There is already defined `T` and `R` parameters in the interface so this should be avoided since it hides the defined parameter from the interface.

The correct usage example would be in the case the interface defines only parameter `R`:

```
public interface Listener<R> {
    <T> Listener<R> get(T t);
}
```

However, even this usage is questionable. The example is clear - the interface works with parameter `R` and only its method uses `T` additionally. Another method without this `<T>` singature would not be able to use `T`.